# Android Emulator won't disable hardware buttons

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I want to test my application on ICS/JB without hardware buttons. I configured Hardware back/Home keys to 'no' (image attached) yet buttons show up in the emulator (image attached). Am I missing something? SDK is up-to-date and Eclipse Version: 4.2.0 Build id: I20120608-1400 Thank You.

Screenshots(sorry, stackoverflow policy prevents me from posting images):

AVD Configuration:
http://postimage.org/image/44jppptjv/

Emulator: http://postimage.org/image/s9kf7fduj/

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an easier way, go to the AVD manager menu, edit the virtual device you want without hardware buttons and un-check "Display a skin with hardware controls"